# How can I change the state of a bool using Riverpod State Management?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod, state-management, flutter-state

I'm trying to change the status of the 'TaskCard' from false to true after pressing on the 'ElevatedButton' in 'task*-details-page*.dart' I tried solving this problem without using riverpod as well, but to no avail. I never really used extra in the GoRouter package, but I noticed that it was used in the '*routes.dart*' file. (I'm not working on this alone that's why it was used) I'd rather not use it if complicates things for achieving the goal I mentioned.

***routes.dart***

```
GoRoute(
  path: "/${NamedRoutes.taskDetails}",
  name: NamedRoutes.taskDetails,
  pageBuilder: (context, state) {
    // Retrieve the TaskModel object passed as an extra parameter
    final task = state.extra as TaskModel;

    return NoTransitionPage(
      key: state.pageKey,
      child: TaskDetails(
          taskModel: task),
    );
  },
),
```

***task_model.dart***

```
class TaskModel {
  final String id;
  final String taskTitle;
  final String taskDescription;
  final bool taskStatus;
  final Timestamp? timestamp;
  final String projectId;
  TaskModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.taskTitle,
    required this.taskDescription,
    required this.taskStatus,
    this.timestamp,
    required this.projectId,
  });
```

task_repository.dart

```
class TasksRepo {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<void> createTask({
    required String taskTitle,
    required String taskDescription,
    required bool taskStatus,
    required String projectId,
  }) async {
    try {
      DocumentReference documentReference =
          _firestore.collection('tasks').doc();

      TaskModel createTask = TaskModel(
        projectId: projectId,
        id: documentReference.id,
        taskDescription: taskDescription,
        taskStatus: false,
        taskTitle: taskTitle,
        timestamp: Timestamp.now(),
      );

      await documentReference.set(createTask.toMap());
      printSuccess('Task added successfully!');
    } catch (e) {
      printError('Error adding task: $e');
      throw ('Error adding task: $e');
    }
  }
Future<void> changeTaskstatus({
    required String taskId,
    required bool taskStatus,
  }) async {
    try {
      DocumentReference documentReference =
          _firestore.collection('tasks').doc(taskId);

      // Update only the taskStatus field
      await documentReference.update({'taskStatus': !taskStatus});

      printSuccess('Task status changed successfully!');
    } catch (e) {
      printError('Error changing task status: $e');
      throw ('Error changing task status: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<TaskModel?> getTasksById({required String taskId}) async {
    try {
      DocumentSnapshot projectSnapshot =
          await _firestore.collection('tasks').doc(taskId).get();

      if (projectSnapshot.exists) {
        return TaskModel.fromMap(
            projectSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw ('Error getting project by ID: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

***task_state.dart** (just in case it's needed)*

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class TasksState {
  // Add a provider container to manage the state of each task
  final ProviderContainer container = ProviderContainer();

  // Your existing state properties
  final bool isLoading;
  final String error;

  TasksState({
    this.isLoading = false,
    this.error = '',
  });

  TasksState copyWith({
    bool? isLoading,
    String? error,
  }) {
    return TasksState(
      isLoading: isLoading ?? this.isLoading,
      error: error ?? this.error,
    );
  }
}
```

***task_controller.dart***

```
class TaskController extends StateNotifier<TasksState> {
  final TasksRepo _tasksRepo;
  TaskController(super.state, this._tasksRepo);

  Future<void> createTask({
    required String taskTitle,
    required String taskDescription,
    required bool taskStatus,
    required projectId,
    // required DateTime dateTime,
    // required Color color,
  }) async {
    state = state.copyWith(isLoading: true);
    try {
      await _tasksRepo.createTask(
          taskDescription: taskDescription,
          taskStatus: false,
          taskTitle: taskTitle,
          projectId: projectId);
      state = state.copyWith(
        isLoading: false,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      state = state.copyWith(isLoading: false, error: e.toString());
    }
  }
   Future<void> changeTaskStatus(
      {required String taskId,
      required String taskTitle,
      required String taskDescription,
      required bool taskStatus,
      required String projectId}) async {
    try {
      state = state.copyWith(isLoading: true);

      await _tasksRepo.changeTaskstatus(
        taskId: taskId,
        taskStatus: taskStatus,
      );
      print(taskStatus.toString());
      state = state.copyWith(
        isLoading: false,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      state = state.copyWith(isLoading: false, error: e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

***task_provider.dart***

```
import 'package:capstone_project/app/modules/tasks/domain/providers/controllers/task_controller.dart';
import 'package:capstone_project/app/modules/tasks/domain/providers/state/task_state.dart';
import 'package:capstone_project/app/modules/tasks/domain/providers/repository/task_repo.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final taskRepoProvider = Provider<TasksRepo>((ref) {
  return TasksRepo();
});

final tasksStateNotifierProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<TaskController, TasksState>(
  (ref) => TaskController(
    TasksState(),
    ref.read(
      taskRepoProvider,
    ),
  ),
);
```

***taskdetailspage.dart***

```
import 'package:capstone_project/app/modules/tasks/domain/models/task_model.dart';
import 'package:capstone_project/app/modules/tasks/domain/providers/task_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class TaskDetails extends ConsumerWidget {
  final TaskModel taskModel;

  TaskDetails({required this.taskModel});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(taskModel.taskTitle), // Display the task title
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("description: ${taskModel.taskDescription}"),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Text("task status: ${taskModel.taskStatus}"),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final taskRepoProviders =
                    ref.read(tasksStateNotifierProvider.notifier);
                taskRepoProviders.changeTaskStatus(
                    taskId: taskModel.id,
                    taskTitle: taskModel.taskTitle,
                    taskDescription: taskModel.taskDescription,
                    taskStatus: taskModel.taskStatus,
                    projectId: taskModel.projectId);
              },
              child: Text("Please")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

part of the code inside ***task_page.dart*** (the page before *task_details.dart* which contains the ElevatedButton that switch the bool from false to true)

```
StreamBuilder<List<TaskModel>>(
  stream: ref
      .watch(taskRepoProvider)
      .fetchTasks(projectId: projectModel.projectID),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      listTasks = snapshot.data!;
      return ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: context.screenWidth * 0.015,
            right: context.screenWidth * 0.015,
            bottom: context.screenHeight * 0.05,
            top: context.screenHeight * 0.01),
        itemCount: listTasks.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => {
              context.pushNamed(
                NamedRoutes.taskDetails,
                extra: listTasks[index],
              )
            },
            child: TaskCardWithTimelineWidget(
              task: listTasks[index],
              firstItem: index,
              lastItem: index,
              projectModel: projectModel,
            ),
          );
        },
      );
```

I tried using riverpod in many different ways, I looked different articles and examples, but no luck solving the issue, I'm not sure if it's because using extra in the 'routes.dart' file, but it making things a bit more complicated, or maybe not compatible with the way I'm doing things. I wouldn't mind using the regular Provider package, but solving this would be a big help.

Comment: Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: Adding to Randal's comment, handling this case would be much easier if you migrate to the new APIs. You can see the migration guide [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/from_state_notifier). Also you can see an example of using Riverpod with go_router [here](https://github.com/dhafinrayhan/dummymart).